# Tweak Model or Process to Focus More on Category Values for Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, statistical-significance, python, catboost

I have built a machine learning model using Catboost and I noticed something as I examine the results. When I am looking at the results there is a big fluctuation in the errors between my test set and the prediction for certain values in a category I have. I call this 'Category1'. Here's what I see:

- Category1 value is 1, the error is off by 10%. There's about 100 rows.
- Category1 value is 2, the error is off by 5%. There's about 150 rows.
- Cateogry1 value is 3, the error is off by 40%. There's about 120 rows.

If I just did a simple average instead of a Catboost prediction for Category1 when the value is 3, the error would be much lower. Is there a way to emphasize this Category1 feature more instead of the other features I have? There's 10 other features in my data. What I believe is happening is it is putting more of an importance on other features before Category1.

I don't have to stick to Catboost if there a way to do this outside of this model.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: you're concerned with the difference between the test error and the training error?  I'm not familiar with Catboost, but if there's a big difference between your training error and your prediction error, it may be that your model is overfitting for certain categories.  If that's the case, you would want to simplify your model, perhaps by merging categories if possible.

Comment: @dante Sorry for the confusion. I'm actually concerned about the test error. There's not really a difference between the test error and the training error. What I am trying to figure out is if there is a way to specify within my model to focus on the category more. One way I thought of doing is just building a model specifically for each category value. So Category1 value is equal to one, first model. Category1 value is equal to two, second model, and so forth. And then once it input comes in, in runs the model for each value. But, is there a way to just have a master model that can do that?

Comment: @ DS_Misc Ok, my bad.  I don't know anything about Catboost so I probably can't be of help.